# Docker compose for Nodered on linux machine giving curl: (56) Recv failure: Connection reset by peer

Tags: linux, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, node-red

I am running my docker compose to start a nodered container on linux machine here are the logs of the container

```
[info] Server now running at http://127.0.0.1:1886/
[warn] Encrypted credentials not found
[info] Starting flows  
[info] Started flows
```

But while performing curl on `http://127.0.0.1:1886/` it is displaying

```
curl: (56) Recv failure: Connection reset by peer
```

**.env file**

```
ABCD=99966 EFGH=128 PORT=1886
NODE_RED_CREDENTIAL_SECRET='d7fdsiufhweiu23901ds'
```

**docker compose command**

```
 docker-compose -f XYZ/docker-compose.yml --env-file XYZ/99966/128/.env -p projectname up -d
```

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: "3.7"

services:
  node-red:
    image: nodered/node-red:latest
    environment:
      ABCD: "${ABCD}"
      EFGH: "${EFGH}"
      PORT: "${PORT}"

    ports:
      - "${PORT}:1880"
    volumes:
      - XYZ/${ABCD}/${EFGH}:/data
```

I am expecting to run the node-red container using docker compose. I am using settings.js file for authentication using a token.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The port (1886) number printed in the Node-RED logs are what port the service is listening on inside the container.

You have explicitly mapped that to a different value on the host machine with the `ports` section of the docker-compose.yml file.

```
    ports:
      - "${PORT}:1880"
```

This explicitly tells docker to map port `1886` (the value of the `PORT` env var) on the host to port `1880` on the contain.

Except the container is not listening on port `1880`, but on port `1886` as shown in the logs. This is because you have also told Docker to pass the `PORT` env var into the container so it's in scope when Node-RED starts up so it uses that value. Hence why NR is listening on port `1886` instead of port `1880`.

You have 2 choices

1. Leave the `environment` section alone and direct map both ports together

   ```
   environment:
     ABCD: "${ABCD}"
     EFGH: "${EFGH}"
     PORT: "${PORT}"
   ports:
     - "${PORT}:${PORT}"
   ```
2. Remove the `PORT` entry from the `environment` section

   ```
   environment:
     ABCD: "${ABCD}"
     EFGH: "${EFGH}"
   ports:
     - "${PORT}:1880"
   ```

Comment: So what change should I make to the existing one.

Comment: I've told you how to change the curl command, why do you think anything else needs changing?

Comment: Am I not able to use curl http://127.0.0.1:1886 because i need different ports for different projects.

Comment: I mean why the port binding not working in my case like.

Comment: Think about it for a second, if `- "${PORT}:1880" maps the internal 1886 to external 1880, what do you think you could do to map 1886 to 1886?

Comment: The port number on the left is host port and port number on the right is container port right, so if we use 127.0.0.1:1886 on host machine that should point to 127.0.0.1:1880 right.

Comment: But you've passed in the `PORT` environment variable, which tells NR to listen on the value of that env var (as can clearly be seen in the logs) so you need BOTH sides to be 1886 or remove `PORT` from the `environment` section to keep the NR in the container listening on 1880

Comment: My program consists of different projects running on different ports that use node-red container at a time, will that work fine after.

Comment: Read the edited answer